# can we not assign url or action when using Form::open() in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a register form, and want to send an ajax call when click button. I read some tutorials and they all use '' for the first array element, such as

```
{{ Form::open(array('', 'class' => 'form_reg')) }}
```

for the ajax part, put the url that will be requested with method post, such as

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "some url"
    ...
});
```

But after i click submit, it shows 405 method not allowed error, then i find ' ' gives the url of the form itself, its method is get.

is there any way to not assign url or action when using Form::open()?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with uppercase method name

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some url"
    ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ shows as uppercase method name.